# Is there a way to make my macbook automatically execute a script every time I connect it to an external monitor?

Tags: macos, display, command-line, script

I would like to make my macbook automatically connect to a specific wifi and launch [Lunar](https://lunar.fyi/) everytime I connect it to my external monitor, and vice versa when I unplug it, but don't know where to start...

I could write a script that keeps checking whether or not an external monitor is connected every, for example, 60 seconds, but I would like to do something like "event driven" that is neither checking nor doing anything at all until an event ("external monitor plugged" or "external monitor unplugged") occurs.

Any hint?

Answer (score 3):

No one answered and I'm still looking for a simpler solution but I've found a workaround creating a little SwiftUI app.

```swift
//
//  ContentView.swift
//  HomeSweetHome
//
//  Created by Daniel Falbo on 20/08/2020.
//  Copyright © 2020 Daniel Falbo. All rights reserved.
//

import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    func execute(script: String) {
        let task = Process()
        task.launchPath = "/usr/bin/env"
        task.arguments = ["/Applications/HomeSweetHome.app/Contents/bin/\(script)"]
        task.launch()
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("")
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: NSApplication.didChangeScreenParametersNotification)) { _ in
                self.execute(script: NSScreen.screens.count > 1 ? "connect" : "disconnect")
        }
    }
    
}
```

It's basically just a Text object that listens for [didChangeScreenParametersNotification](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsapplication/1428749-didchangescreenparametersnotific).
Since the Text object must be alive in order to listen for notifications, an istance of the app must always be opened or minimized (does anyone have any idea on how to avoid this?).
Every time it receives a notification, it checks the number of connected displays, if there's only one display connected, it executes my `disconnect` script, else it executes my `connect` script.

This is what the scripts look like:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh
#
# connect
#
open -a Lunar
networksetup -setairportnetwork en0 $SSID $PASSWORD
```

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh
#
# disconnect
#
killall Lunar
networksetup -setairportnetwork en0 $SSID $PASSWORD
```

And this is what the app looks like

[image: HomeSweetHome]

[This](https://superuser.com/questions/286457/connect-to-wifi-network-using-mac-terminal) helped me connecting to a wifi programmatically

Comment: Brilliant code! Thanks so much for sharing it - I can see lots of people wanting to craft this to automate their setups.

Answer (score 0):

On macOS 13, use `MenuBarExtra` to create a status bar app without window:

```
//
//  MonitorStatusApp.swift
//  MonitorStatus
//
//  Created by ZJG on 2023/6/28.
//

import SwiftUI

@main
struct MonitorStatusApp: App {
    @State private var sc = NSScreen.screens.count
    func execute() {
        sc = NSScreen.screens.count
        if (sc < 2) {
            return
        }
        let task = Process()
        task.launchPath = "/usr/bin/env"
        task.arguments = ["/Applications/auto_screen_setup.sh"]
        task.launch()
    }
    
    var body: some Scene {
        // pass
        MenuBarExtra {
            Button("Quit") {NSApplication.shared.terminate(nil)}.keyboardShortcut("q")
        } label: {
            Image(systemName: "display.2").onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: NSApplication.didChangeScreenParametersNotification)) { _ in
                self.execute()}
            Text(String(sc))
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).